# HTML Images Flowing

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to put a number of images inside and div. The div has a fixed height but the width will be dynamic depending on the number of images. I'm not sure what CSS to apply to the img tag for the containing DIV. I've attached an example below.
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
How do I go about about styling the images in side the DIV? I've tried floating them and just letting them place themselves but that's not work.

Comment: So.. what's your question?

Comment: Have you considered using the jQuery Masonry or Isotope plugin?

Comment: @JoshC I think riglestpierre wants us to read his mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ it's the "de facto" standard.

Answer (score 1):

just make a div container with img tags in it. Then apply this css:

```
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  float: left;  
  padding: 3px;
}
```

All the images will naturally float to the left. If you want a scroll bar you will have to set a width and overflow.